# Are regex reviews allowed on this site?

Tags: support, scope

I have a working regular expression and I want to have it reviewed. Can I post it on this site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [regex](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag wiki, they are allowed as long as they're also tagged with the relevant language tag (questions with just [regex](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex) may be closed).  They must also still involve real code and not just hypothetical regex.

Comment: In other words: Don't just include the regex, also include some code that is using the regex.